# Paypal button not linking while using Paypal pro

Tags: paypal

We are running CiviCRM version 4.6.3  under Wordpress. We use Paypal Pro for payments. We created an Event registration and the registration page shows a Paypal button and the text:

"If you have a PayPal account, you can click the PayPal button to continue. "

but the Paypal button does not link to Paypal, but simply acts like the "Continue" button​, giving an error that the credit card info has not been filled out.

This only happens with Event registration. With contributions, the same button goes to Paypal as it should.

Can anyone help us fix this?

Comment: Weird - so it works fine for Donations but not for Events. Are these public links? Are you using a Price Set for the Event?

Comment: That code has had many fixes applied since 4.2.4 & it's likely that upgrading will fix it

Comment: I made a mistake - 4.2.4 is our Wordpress version. Our CIvicrm is 4.6.3

Comment: These are public links. And I am using a price set.

Comment: I found the problem. I had "BIlling address required" turned on and that forced CiviEvent to demand more info and not let the user go to Paypal. I turned that off and it works.

Comment: Can you add the last as an answer and tick it to close this off? Though i don't quite see why if 'billing address' was required and you filled it in, it should then fail to go to Paypal

Comment: I did add it as an answer and will close as soon as it let's me. The problem appears to be a bug and I've raised it as an issue in Jira

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. I had "BIlling address required" turned on and that forced CiviEvent to demand more info and not let the user go to Paypal. I turned that off and it works.